Are there purely 1D instabilities in fluid dynamics?
If I have a purely 1D fluid flow governed by the 1D Navier-Stokes equations (let's assume compressible flow for more generality), are there any instabilities that can happen? It seems like you'd need at least two dimensions to have instabilities like Rayleigh-Taylor, Kelvin-Helmholtz, etc.. I'm not sure if there are well-known 1D instabilities, or if it's just impossible to have one.
Any insight would be appreciated!

Very interesting question. I'm not fully sure, but seems there's a 1D model of RT instabilities in supernova explosion used.

In some sense yes, you are essentially describing Burger’s equation, and in the inviscid limit, you have the development of shocks
